# Autocomplete ComboBox for dependent list with INDIRECT and SUBSTITUTE

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, substitution

So, I got two drop-down lists with one (B) dependent on the other (A).
As the names of the ranges for B have a few symbols in them which are not supposed to be shown in A, I solved this with a combination of INDIRECT and SUBSTITUTE.
That worked all well until I brought in a ComboBox to autocomplete once the user starts typing. While this works well for A, the INDIRECT/SUBSTITUTE formula for B throws it. I found several solutions for simple INDIRECT formulas but nothing for the combination with SUBSTITUTE.
I hope someone can help me with this :-)

My formula is

`=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B19," ","_"),",","_"),":","_"),"&","_"),"/","_")&"_")`

Comment: Maybe adding a hidden field and doing the substation before hand? Not sure.